# strongly typed views and decimals

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

looking really for some advice on how i should handle the following scenario.
i have a inputviewmodel with a decimal field.  the value will be inserted into a SQL db with the following precision and scale: 18,2.
if the user enters 100000000000000000.00 an error is returned from the db:

> "Parameter value
>   '100000000000000000.00' is out of
>   range."

How should i be handling this?i.e. to stop the user from entering this value.  i do have a validation layer.. but this value does parse into a decimal.

many thanks in advance

Comment: Are negative values allowed...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could decorate the property in your InputViewModel with a Range attribute.

MSDN doc on RangeAttribute for your InputViewModel:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

you'll be looking for a usage like:

`[Range(Maximum: 100000000)]`